# (solved) Generating URIs with --print-uris for the "upgrade" command with apt-get

Tags: apt, upgrade

I follow the guide  [AptGet/Offline/PrintUris](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/PrintUris).

Everything works using the command:

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install mypackage...
```

But it doesn't works for the command:

```
sudo apt-get --print-uris upgrade
```

I don't view URLs [like in this paste](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SZRtTMJ3Y5/). Is it possible to generate URLs for the "upgrade" command?

Comment: added link to nopaste output

Comment: Your input is different in the paste. You left out --yes, or you didn't hit 'Y' for apt to continue. The uris print *after* the prompt.

Comment: I follow the guide, anyway adding "--yes" nothing change in the output

Comment: Did you run a `sudo apt-get update` first?  Also, if this is an offline system, then there may simply be no uris to print. How will the system know what is available if it is offline?

Comment: the system is online... same command but for one package works

Comment: I try: apt-get update, and this make a package to download , and now command find a package to download and show me url, before in fact there were no packages to download... thank you a lot

Comment: how can I set this "ask" solved by user535733 ? thanks